# Ajax response to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to put the ajax response to a Javascript array.

For example

Server Side

```
 $response = '{x1:12, x2:32, x3:0}'
 echo $respons;
```

Client side

```
 var arrayObject = [{x1:132, x2:332, x3:320}]
 arrayobject += [ajaxResponse];
```

Comment: Very vague, you need to add more detail in order for anyone to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSON.parse to convert the text to a real object and Array.push to add it to the array.

```
arrayobject.push(JSON.parse(ajaxResponse));
```

Comment: Based on the question I think this is the best answer.

Comment: and the string should be: '{"x1":12, "x2":32, "x3":0}'